# unexpected input at end when move code as a separate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got strange problems. I try to load variables from cookies before I do anything else. Here is the partial code

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start != -1) {
        c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = document.cookie.length;
        }
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
}
return "";
}


     function loadCookies(name,assign) {
            var cookie_name = getCookie(name);
            if ( cookie_name != "" ) {
                var json_str = getCookie(cookie_name);
                assign = JSON.parse(json_str);  
            }
            else {

            }
        }

        //all main functions starts here

        $(document).ready(function() {

        alert(listCookies());

        //if ( getCookie('foodbasket') != "" ) {
        //  var json_str = getCookie('foodbasket');
        //  foodArray = JSON.parse(json_str);
        //  alert("yep");   
        //}

        loadCookies('foodbasket',foodArray);

.....
}
```

foodArray is a global variable I declare at top of the JS file. Now comes the problem. **If I write the code inside document ready , then there will be no errors.
If I try to move the code outside the function(since I have to load couple variables), it gives me error:** unexpected input at end.The error line is

```
foodArray = JSON.parse(json_str);
```

I am very sure I correctly record the array into cookies.

Comment: Is this function in the <head> tag?

Comment: @Cranio everything is in a js file

Comment: So, is this file loaded in the <head> tag?

Comment: @Cranio yes! Correctly load

Comment: Try including the JS file just before the last closing body tag.

Comment: What is the value for `json_str`? Because of wrongly formatted data, parsing could fail. Try to `log` value of `json_str`

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. Because I call get cookies twice. It gives me a wrong format.That cause the problem. Thanks!